# Intellij Idea not finding jar

Tags: java, maven, servlets, intellij-idea, javax

I have a single java file to compile. It uses javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar. I added it to maven with mvn-install and it says it built successfully. However, in Intellij it still throws errors during compilation saying:

```
package javax.servlet does not exist.
```

This was after restarting it.

Am I missing anything with adding this jar to my program?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: There isn't one. I just have a single .java file.

Comment: How do you resolve the dependencies of your project ? You need to say somewhere what JARs your project needs to compile.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, the link you posted helped with managing module dependencies. I was able to add the jar. I also created a pom.xml in the project. Not sure which one did it, but I got it to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a pom.xml file in order to build a maven based project.  In short, a pom.xml file is used to tell maven how exactly to build your project, and what dependencies it requires.  I'd strongly recommend reading the quickstart guide for maven [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: Thanks, I created a pom.xml plus added the jar in File -> Project Structure -> Modules. It compiles now.

Comment: @dansmith841 -- you shouldn't add the jar manually to the module, maven does this for you. Close your project, then open a project, choosing your pom as the project file. Idea will do the rest, including importing your dependencies for you.